# Disappearing attribute values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, attribute-table, editing

Using ArcMap 10.1, I’m editing values in a feature class which was sent to me from within my organization. I realized I had a problem when trying to change the symbology of this feature class- the values I updated appear in the attribute table but some don’t appear in the Properties dialog box when I try to change the Symbology to categories/unique values (trying to visually highlight the new values I've added).

The structure of the attribute table cannot be changed as it was created to link with other systems. The problem is only occurring with one field; other fields which I updated do have their unique values appear in the Properties dialog box. I checked to see if this was created to be a Read-only field and it was not... Is there some protection on the feature class I don't know about? Did the edits I made somehow not get stored? Edits were made using field calculator + some manual edits in a Edit session which have all been saved.

Comment: Do all of the values show up when you try to build a definition query or a select by attributes operation?  Just something to try out...

Comment: @mr.adam yes in fact they do... any idea why they just seem to not be there when trying to edit symbology?

Comment: Does the field that's giving you problems have a domain or subtype attached to it?

Comment: Is the FC using representation rules for symbology?

Comment: I have had similar problems in the past where if I stopped the edit session (and/or restarted it), things began working normally again. While it would answer the why, it might provide a workaround. How many categories/unique values are we talking about?

Comment: No, I'm not sure why that would happen, just seemed like a good way to double check that the records had definitely been updated... The only times I've experienced something like what you're describing is when I began by importing a symbology scheme from another layer, and then I wanted to add more attributes to the symbology scheme in the new layer... Are you beginning by applying symbology from another layer?

Comment: I exported the data to a new workspace and the problem disappeared! I am still trying to understand what was happening. The issue was occurring outside of an edit session, without representation rules. It could be stemming from domains/subtypes, I'm not too familiar with how these work.

Answer (score 0):

In the symbology tab, go to Add Values, then click the Complete List button. All the values that are not currently symbolized should appear.  Highlight the new values and hit OK to add them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried that but the new values do not show up. I also tried adding a New Value to the list and entering one of my new values (the field is numeric) but the count shows up as "?" and nothing is symbolized on the map.

Comment: What happens if you open up a new MXD, add the fc and symbolize values?  Do they appear then?

Comment: I tried that too in multiple MXDs, still the same problem. I noticed the problem a few days ago and it has recurred after shutting down and re-starting Arc and computer.